# ClearFocus on a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have an application containing a TextBox with an auto-suggest like this :

```
    <Grid x:Name="getStringGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="getStringBox" Text="{Binding Path=GetString, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" KeyDown="contextBox_KeyDown"/>
            <Popup x:Name="getStringPopup"
                   AllowsTransparency="True"
                   Placement="Bottom"
                   IsOpen="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=getStringBox, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                <ListBox SnapsToDevicePixels="{Binding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                         KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ListString}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                             
                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=GetString}"/>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
```

It's works fine but I have some trouble to close the popup `getStringPopup`. When an user press return I want to update my selectedItem and close the popup.

My code :

```
private void contextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        String myString = getStringBox.Text;
        (DataContext as ViewModels.MainViewModel).AddString(myString );
        bool focus = getStringBox.IsFocused;
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();    
        focus = getStringBox.IsFocused;
    }
}
```

The function `Keyboard.ClearFocus()` reset correctly the focus, but `getStringBox.IsFocused` is still `True`.

Can you help me ?

Comment: you probably need to set your focus elsewhere, since I don't know your entire xaml I can't give u the control names but you can try focusing on a panel or another control with adding this line to your code : MainGrid.Focus();

Comment: I just added `getStringGrid.Focus();` before `Keyboard.ClearFocus();` and it's works fine !
Thank you