# WPF TextBox does not lose focus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

I knwow there are many other who wrote about this but the suggested solutions don't solve my problem.

I've got a sort of gallery and I need that when the user edits the number specified in the `TextBox` automatically the image is updated.

Initially I tried with `LostFocus` event, but it doesn't always fire [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539053/what-is-the-reason-why-textbox-does-not-lose-focus-in-certain-cases-and-how-can).

If I bind the property as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437823/why-a-textbox-does-not-lose-the-focus-when-acting-over-a-menu-in-wpf), I have too many events if the number has more than one digit.

Then I tried to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489032/wpf-remove-focus-when-clicking-outside-of-a-textbox), but it doesn't work.

This is how my `TextBox` is defined:

```
  <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding NImageShown}" FontSize="18" 
           LostFocus="ImageIndex_OnLostFocus"
           Name="ImageIndex" Height="40" Width="60" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
           Focusable="True">
  </TextBox>
```

I implemented the third solution by attaching the window to `MouseDown` event:

```
<Window x:Class="...."
    .....
     MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"....>

 private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
      if (ImageIndex.IsFocused)
         Keyboard.ClearFocus();

  }
```

With this solution I sawy that `ImageIndex.IsFocused` remains true even after `Keyboard.ClearFocus()`: this is the reason why I think that solution does not fix my problem.

Any help is really appreciate!

**EDIT**
Changes based on the suggestions:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Name="GridTextbox">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       .....
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding NImageShown}" FontSize="18" LostFocus="ImageIndex_OnLostFocus"
                         Name="ImageIndex" Height="40" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Focusable="True"></TextBox>
                <Label Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Content="{Binding NTotalImages}" FontSize="18" Padding="5,0,5,0" Margin="5,5,5,5" />
       </StackPanel>
 </Grid>

 private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     if (ImageIndex.IsFocused)
     {
         GridTextbox.Focus();
         Keyboard.ClearFocus();
     }
 }
```

Even with these changes, `LostFocus` doesn't fire.

**SOLUTION**

Change the xaml as suggested in this way and keep the code behind as written before:

```
 <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding NImageShown}" FontSize="18" 
          LostKeyboardFocus="ImageIndex_OnLostFocus" 
          KeyDown="ImageIndex_OnLostFocus"
          Name="ImageIndex" Height="40" Width="60" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
          Focusable="True">
  </TextBox>
```

Comment: When do you want to lose the focus? are you sure that window_mousedown is getting fired, and you are not setting the focus again in another sentence?

Comment: True. The application will be used on a touchscreen, so I want to lose focus when the user click on the window and when the ENTER key is pressed.

Comment: Can you try to set the focus in the grid that contains your ImageIndex `Grid.Focus()` element and then `Keyboard.ClearFocus()`?, because maybe is a problem about scope

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226094/clearfocus-on-a-textbox

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I'm going to edit my post so you can see the code.

Comment: have you tried LostKeyboardFocus instead of LostFocus event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview